# how to translate the hostname solaris?

Tags: unix, hostname

can any one translate or explain the following unix script for me please, when i actually run the script in the solaris server, it gives me the server name, but not really sure how this script work, can any one explain it in simple baby language ? Thanks

```
TEXTDOMAIN=SUNW_OST_OSCMD export TEXTDOMAIN

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        /bin/uname -n
elif [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        /bin/uname -S $1
else
        echo `/bin/gettext "Usage: hostname [name]"`
        exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

`$#` reads command line arguments

if there are none call `uname -n`

if there is one call `uname -S $1`  (which is the command line argument.)

See [man uname](http://www.rdg.ac.uk:8081/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/wsi14/poplog/man/1/uname) to discover the differences in these calls.

Comment: the command line is /usr/bin/hostname.sh , do you mean if the hostname.sh is not found then call uname -n , if found then call uname -S "/usr/bin/hostname.sh" ........ am I correct?

Comment: @Big Beetle Fan I understand that the script you posted is /usr/bin/hostname as I said it simply calls either `uname -n` or `uname -S $1` depending on if you call hostname with an argument e.g. `hostname foo`

Comment: thanks mate, one more question, there is also a else condition, will this else condition be ever met at all? my understanding is that the if and elseif will cover all the situations...

Comment: @Big Beetle Fan examine the if conditions, if there are zero do `uname -n`, if there is one do `uname -S $1` otherwise (so if there are more than one arguments passed, `hostname foo bar baz`) print the usage. It expects zero or one arguments. More result in the usage being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If the script is executed with 0 arguments 
it will just run uname [manpage](http://manpages.unixforum.co.uk/man-pages/unix/solaris-10-11_06/1/uname-man-page.html%20manpage) printing you system name

if script is executed with 1 argument
it will change your system name ( you have to be superuser)

else prints usage